# Ошибка json появляется только на одном компьютере?

Tags: python

С websocket клиента прилетает запрос, который исправен (`{type: "some_type", "payload": {"query": "input value"}}`) , и он идет в функцию `work_with_user_request` и в строчке `response = qa_chain({"query": message})` возникает ошибка
При чем эта ошибка появляется только на одном компьютере, на другом ее нет и все отрабатывает хорошо. Версии Python совпадают (3.11.2), версии пакетов совпадают, переменные среды Path обновил. Переменная `prompt_template` валидна. Что может быть не так?

```
retriever = vectordb2.as_retriever(search_type="mmr", search_kwargs={
                                   "k": 6, "fetch_k": 50})  # Контекст в 6 релевантных документов
openai = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-4")

# промпт
prompt_template = """На основе предоставленного контекста и случая {some} придумай вопрос длиной строго больше 10 токенов и 2 строго коротких варианта ответа. 1 ответа обязательно неверный. Правильный ответ выпиши. Если не можешь найти информацию в данном контексте скажи, что не знаешь и ничего не придумывай.

Контекст: {context}

Вопрос: {some}

Отвечай как неопытный преподаватель с опытом работы 1 год:
"""

PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    template=prompt_template, input_variables=["context", "some"]
)

# Create the chain to answer questions и добавим промп
chain_type_kwargs = {"prompt": PROMPT}
qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0.7),
    chain_type="stuff",
    retriever=retriever,
    chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs,  # промпт
    return_source_documents=True
)


def work_with_user_request(message):
    try:
        response = qa_chain({"query": message})

        return response["result"]
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f"При отправке ответа произошла ошибка: {e}")

async def response(websocket, path):
    print("New connection")

    while True:
        request_from_client = await websocket.recv()  # запрос от клиента
        request_from_client_as_obj = json.loads(request_from_client)
        type_from_client = request_from_client_as_obj["type"]

        response = {"result": "Invalid request"}

        # отправка ответа для определенного типа запроса
        if type_from_client == "USER-REQUEST":
            response["result"] = work_with_user_request(
                request_from_client_as_obj["payload"]["query"])

        response["current_type"] = type_from_client

        # отправка ответа клиенту
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(response))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    st_ser = websockets.serve(response, "localhost", 8831)

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(st_ser)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Ошибка:

```
Invalid \uXXXX escape: line 1 column 4246 (char 4245)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\alexe\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\ai\LangChainChromaDB.py", line 170, in work_with_user_request
    response = qa_chain({"query": message})
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 292, in __call__
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 286, in __call__
    self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\retrieval_qa\base.py", line 137, in _call
    docs = self._get_docs(question, run_manager=_run_manager)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\retrieval_qa\base.py", line 217, in _get_docs
    return self.retriever.get_relevant_documents(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\schema\retriever.py", line 208, in get_relevant_documents
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\schema\retriever.py", line 201, in get_relevant_documents
    result = self._get_relevant_documents(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\vectorstores\base.py", line 571, in _get_relevant_documents        
    docs = self.vectorstore.max_marginal_relevance_search(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\vectorstores\chroma.py", line 467, in max_marginal_relevance_search    docs = self.max_marginal_relevance_search_by_vector(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\vectorstores\chroma.py", line 415, in max_marginal_relevance_search_by_vector
    results = self.__query_collection(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\utils\utils.py", line 33, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\vectorstores\chroma.py", line 156, in __query_collection
    return self._collection.query(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chromadb\api\models\Collection.py", line 220, in query
    return self._client._query(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chromadb\api\segment.py", line 488, in _query
    vector_reader = self._manager.get_segment(collection_id, VectorReader)     
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chromadb\segment\impl\manager\local.py", line 144, in get_segment
    instance = self._instance(self._segment_cache[collection_id][scope])       
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chromadb\segment\impl\manager\local.py", line 170, in _instance
    instance.start()
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chromadb\segment\impl\vector\local_hnsw.py", line 80, in start
    self._subscription = self._consumer.subscribe(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chromadb\db\mixins\embeddings_queue.py", line 205, in subscribe
    self._backfill(subscription)
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chromadb\db\mixins\embeddings_queue.py", line 296, in _backfill
    metadata=json.loads(row[5]) if row[5] else None,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode     
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode 
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \uXXXX escape: line 1 column 4246 (char 4245)
```

Comment: Пробовали проверить кодировку?

Comment: Посмотреть бы, что там на позиции 4245 или 4246 в первой строке json-а. Вернее в `message`, что ли.

Comment: В обработчике исключения добавьте вывод `print(repr(message))`, и посмотрите на чем там падает

Comment: А вообще, нужен весь трэйсбэк, чтобы понимать, где именно ошибка возникла.

Comment: у всего кодировка "utf-8"

Comment: все данные приходят, в message все в порядке

Comment: Уберите обработку ошибки и посмотрите полный трейсбэк (и добавьте его в вопрос), или выведите трэйсбэк через модуль traceback: `import traceback` и потом добавьте `traceback.print_exception(e)` в блоке except. По приведенной одной строке ошибки ничего сказать нельзя.

Comment: добавил tracebak

Comment: Где размещен файл `LangChainChromaDB.py` на компьютере, где программа работает без ошибки? ОС одинаковые на обоих компах?

Comment: на моем компе 10 винда на другом 11